# regex to remove hyphens and spaces

Tags: python, regex

I've got the string:

> ```
> <u>40 -04-11</u>
> ```

How do I remove the spaces and hyphens so it returns 400411?

Currently I've got this:

```
(<u[^>]*>)(\-\s)(<\/u>)
```

But I can't figure out why it isn't working. Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [You will bring doom upon us all!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: ah, if I was trying to parse xml or html, I would use a html/xml parser, but it isn't either! It's just a lot of junk in a text file.

Comment: @cwallenpoole I would rather say: Pavlovian reflex

Comment: @Eyquem Mmmm... dinner. (Great, now I want steak)

Comment: @cwallenpoole What do you mean ?

Comment: @Eyquem When Pavlov rang a bell, his dogs all thought that it was time for dinner, and so their mouths watered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(<u[^>]*>)(\-\s)(<\/u>)
```

Your pattern above doesn't tell your regex where to expect numbers.

```
(<u[^>]*>)(?:-|\s|(\d+))*(<\/u>)
```

That should get you started, but not being a python guy, I can't give you the exact replacement syntax. Just be aware that the digits are in a repeating capture group.

Edit: This is an edit in response to your comment. Like I said, not a python guy, but this will probably do what you need if you hold your tongue just right.

```
def repl(matchobj):
        if matchobj.group(1) is None:
            return ''
        else:
            return matchobj.group(1)

source = '<u>40 -04-11</u>40 -04-11<u>40 -04-11</u>40 -04-11'
print re.sub(r'(?:\-|\s|(\d+))(?=[^><]*?<\/u>)', repl, source)
```

Results in:

```
>>>'<u>400411</u>40 -04-11<u>400411</u>40 -04-11'
```

If the above offends the Python deities, I promise to sacrifice the next PHP developer I come across. :)

Comment: I think I can use this for matching, but how do you replace?

Comment: @itwb I edited the answer to include an (admittedly rough) Python example.

Comment: I don't think they want PHP developers (I know I don't).

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need a regex, you could use :

```
>>> '<u>40 -04-11</u>'.replace('-','').replace(' ','')
'<u>400411</u>'
```

Comment: This is just one really small part of the puzzle. I've probably got around 200 <u> unsigned int values which are malformed. they're all in the same document, I just need to clear out spaces and hyphens programatically. (only between the tags <u> and </u> tags)

Comment: Use an HTML or XML parser, visit each `<u>` node, apply wim's double-replace, then replace the content of the `<u>` node with the patched text.

Comment: it's not xml, it doesn't have any formatting, even though it seems like it. <u> stands for unsigned int, in this situation

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl syntax:

```
s{
   (<u[^>]*>) (.*?) (</u>)
}{
   my ($start, $body, $end) = ($1, $2, $3);
   $body =~ s/[-\s]//g;
   $start . $body . $end       
}xesg;
```

Or if Python doesn't have an equivalent to /e,

```
my $out = '';
while (
   $in =~ m{
      \G (.*?) 
      (?: (<u[^>]*>) (.*?) (</u>) | \z )
   }sg
) {
   my ($pre, $start, $body, $end) = ($1, $2, $3, $4);
   $out .= $pre;
   if (defined($start)) {
       $body =~ s/[-\s]//g;
       $out .= $start . $body . $end;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm admittedly not very good at regexes, but the way I would do this is by:

- Doing a match on a `<u>...</u>` pair
- doing a `re.sub` on the bit between the match using `group()`.

That looks like this:

```
example_str = "<u>   76-6-76s</u> 34243vvfv"
tmp = re.search("(<u[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/u>)",example_str).group(2)
clean_str = re.sub("(\D)","",tmp)
>>>'76676'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should expose correctly your problem. I firstly didn't exactly understand it.

Having read your comment  `(only between the tags <u> and </u> tags)` , I can now propose:

```
import re

ss = '87- 453- kol<u>40 -04-11</u> maa78-55 98 12'

print re.sub('(?<=<u>).+?(?=</u>)',
             lambda mat: ''.join(c for c in mat.group() if c not in ' -'),
             ss)
```

result

```
87- 453- kol<u>400411</u> maa78-55 98 12
```